# Angular - Wait for subscription to complete then execute other code

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is my angular function

```
    observeDiaryCreate(){
        this.diarySub = this.diaryService.diaryTrigger$.subscribe((dataVal: boolean) => {
            if(dataVal) {
                if(this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1) {
                    this.baseService.checkFeature('setFeature').subscribe((response: any) => {
                        if(!response) {
                            if((JSON.stringify(data1) !== JSON.stringify(data2))) {
                                this.modafRef = this.modalService.show();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error => {},
                    () => {});
                }
                this.validateDiary();
            } else {
                this.onCancel();
            }
        })
    }
```

Here, I want to execute `this.validateDiary()` method, only after the inner subscribe gets executed. I am trying to stop the code execution by using `return` statement when a specific condition is met. But what is now happening is, both `return` and `this.validateDiary()`  are being executed and first `this.validateDiary()` is being called even before the subscribe. How can I format my code to meet my criteria. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the specific condition is not met what do you want to happen? Also where is data1 and data2 coming from? Either way, RxJS will come to the recue here...just need details

Comment: data1 and data2 are the form values, where old and new values are getting checked whether any change happens within the form

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `this.validateDiary()` gets executed is because once the outer observable emits, you are subscribing to inner observable as well as calling the function, `this.validateDiary()`. If you need to call `this.validateDiary()` only when the inner observable emits, then you can do following.

```
observeDiaryCreate() {
        this.diarySub = this.diaryService.diaryTrigger$
            .pipe(
                filter(dataVal => dataVal && this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1), // a filter to match the condition
                switchMap(() => this.baseService.checkFeature('setFeature')) // mapped to second observable.
            )
            .subscribe(response => {
                if (!response) {
                    if ((JSON.stringify(data1) !== JSON.stringify(data2))) {
                        this.modafRef = this.modalService.show();
                        this.validateDiary();
                    }
                }
            }, error => {});
}
```

Comment: I dont want it to be executed inside  if(this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1) {  this if condition, that is the reason why it is placed after if block

Comment: Are you saying you want to execute the function if the `this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1 is false`, otherwise, the inner observable?

Comment: I want it to be executed within if(dataVal) but not within if(this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1), that too only after the inner subscribe completes.. in other words, synchronous manner..

Comment: `this.validateDiary()` should get executed 1. if `this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1`  condition is not met as well as 2. after inner observables emits?

Comment: correct. it should execute irrespective if the this.isEdit condition output

Comment: Is your `validateDiary()` an observable?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add it at Location 1 or Location 2.

```
    this.baseService.checkFeature('setFeature').subscribe((response: any) => {
                               //Location 1
                                if(!response) {
                                    if((JSON.stringify(data1) !== JSON.stringify(data2))) {
                                        this.modafRef = this.modalService.show();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            error => {},
                            () => {
                                  //Location 2
                                   });
```

Comment: I dont want it to be executed inside  if(this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1) {  this if condition, that is the reason why it is placed after if block

Answer (score 0):

**"I dont want it to be executed inside if(this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1)"**

As per this comment I guess you want to run **this.validateDiary()**; relardless of the condition.
But still you want subscription within to complete before calling **this.validateDiary()**

Just a simple hack. If you closely look

if this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1 is true then **this.validateDiary();** within the subscription will be called. Also **this.validateDiary();** will be called after the sunscription completion

if this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1 is false then **this.validateDiary();** within the else condition will be called

```
observeDiaryCreate(){
        this.diarySub = this.diaryService.diaryTrigger$.subscribe((dataVal: boolean) => {
            if(dataVal) {
                if(this.isEdit && this.statusId != 1) {
                    this.baseService.checkFeature('setFeature').subscribe((response: any) => {
                        if(!response) {
                            if((JSON.stringify(data1) !== JSON.stringify(data2))) {
                                this.modafRef = this.modalService.show();
                            }
                        }
                        this.validateDiary();
                    },
                    error => {},
                    () => {});
                } else {
                   this.validateDiary();
                }
            } else {
                this.onCancel();
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fundamentally asynchronous. There are two possible responses to this:

- subscribe then do synchronous work within the subscribe
- use RxJS pipeable operators to amend the "live" stream

I strongly recommend the 2nd wherever possible.

---

**Question Code**

What you cannot do is the following and expect `synchronousCode2()` not to run:

```
obs$.subscribe((v) => {
    synchronousCode1(v)
    return
})
synchronousCode2()
```

All the code in the subscribe will run whenever `obs$` emits. Until `obs$` completes. `synchronousCode2()` will run no matter what and likely before `synchronousCode1()`. You could put `synchronousCode2()` within the subscribe and update the logic but this is quickly a mess of nested subscriptions.

---

**RxJS to the rescue**

Let's set up the code for a RxJS answer. This will need minor amendments to add to your class, mostly adding `this.`

```
let diaryTrigger$: Observable<boolean> = diaryService.diaryTrigger$;

let hasFormChanged$: Observable<boolean> = of(
  JSON.stringify(data1) !== JSON.stringify(data2)
);

let checkFeatureHasResponse$: Observable<boolean> = baseService
  .checkFeature('setFeature')
  .pipe(
      // !!response is true if response is truthy
      map((response) => !!response)
  );
```

*onCancel*

```
let onCancel$ = diaryTrigger$.pipe(
  // only continue stream if false
  filter((v) => !v),
)
onCancel$.subscribe(() => onCancel()) // don't forget to clean up subscriptions
```

In order to set up running *showModel* or *validateDiary* we need the specific criteria observable

```
// Specific criteria to show modal, else validateDiary:
//    - diaryTrigger$ emits true
//    - isEdit is true
//    - statusId != 1
//    - checkFeatureHasResponse$ emits false
//    - hasFormChanged$ emits true
let specificCriteria$ = diaryTrigger$.pipe(
  filter((v) => v), // only continue stream if true
  switchMap(() =>
    combineLatest([checkFeatureHasResponse$, hasFormChanged$]).pipe(
      map(([checkFeatureHasResponse, hasFormChanged]) => {
        return (
          isEdit && statusId != 1 && !checkFeatureHasResponse && hasFormChanged
        );
      })
    )
  )
);
```

And now it's just a matter of,

```
specificCriteria$.subscribe((specificCriteria) => {
  if (specificCriteria) {
    showModal();
  } else {
    validateDiary();
  }
}); // don't forget to clean up subscriptions
```

---

### [RxJS Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-73972770?file=index.ts)

- `of(x)` - An observable that emits `x` straight away and completes

##### RxJS pipe operators

The following are used within a stream `obs$.pipe(<insert>)`:

- `delay(1000)` - delays a stream by 1 second. Here I've used for testing, i.e models a http delay when combined with `of`, so that `of(x).pipe(delay(1000))` emits `x` after 1 second
- `map(v => newValue(v))` - map *within* the stream to transform emitted values `v` to new value `newValue(v)`
- `filter` - stop some values from continuing within the stream
- `tap` - for side effects, avoid using, useful for debugging `tap(console.log)`
- `switchMap(v => obs$(v))` - when a new value `v` emits, switch and subscribe to `obs$(v)`. The next operator in the stream will see only what `obs$(v)` emits.
- `combineLatest([obs1$, ..., obsn$])` - subscribe to the observables and emit the array of values anytime one of them emits.

##### RxJS Conventions

- observable variables should have a $ appended `obs$`
- subscribe should be simple! do the hard work within the stream
- avoid side effects where possible, bring into the stream if possible
- don't forget to clean up subscriptions, either directly in ngOnDestroy or the `takeUntil(this.destroyed$)` method